# Relationship between the eigenvalues of $A A^T$ and $A^T A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am just starting with SVD. I have the following problem.

> Given $$A=\begin{pmatrix}4&11&14\\8&7&-2\end{pmatrix}$$ calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrices $AA^T$ and $A^TA$.

---

I notice that $A^TA$ and $AA^T$ share two eigenvalues. Since you can break down $A = U \Sigma V^T$,

$$A^TA=V\Sigma^T \Sigma V^T \tag{1}$$

$$AA^T=U\Sigma \Sigma^T U^T \tag{2}$$

Since $U,V$ are orthogonal matrices, they only rotate and mirror, and both $A A^T,A^T A$ are symmetrical with orthogonal eigenvectors, $\Sigma^T \Sigma$ and $\Sigma \Sigma^T$ must be diagonal matrices with eigenvalues. From this its seems clear why they share eigenvalues, but it feels circular to me since you use (1) and (2) to show that $A=U\Sigma V^T$. What is the relationship with eigenvalues and eigenvectors between $AA^T$ and $A^TA$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $A^TAv=\lambda v$.  Then multiplying both sides by $A$, we get $AA^T(Av)=\lambda Av$.  And multiplication by $A^T$ goes the other way, so we have isomorphisms between the non-zero eigenspaces.  If we combine this with the spectral theorem (to argue that we have eigenbases for $AA^T$ and $A^TA$), we get that all the eigenvalues are the same, with the same multiplicities, except possibly for $0$.

One can actually prove something slightly stronger under weaker hypotheses, (you don't need diagonalizability, and it works for $AB$ and $BA$ both being square), but this is enough to explain what is going on here without relying on the existence of SVD.